# What does the author mean here?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am reading a paper and there is a short statement by Author for which I am not sure if I got him right or not. Could someone let me know if my understanding right or not?

He says the following:

"Let $\tilde{P}_0\neq \tilde{P}_1$ be arbitrary probability distributions on an arbitrary measurable space $\Omega$ and let $P_0$, $P_1$ be the distributions of $x=d \tilde{P}_1/d \tilde{P}_0$ under $\tilde{P}_0$ and $\tilde{P}_1$ respectively. Then, $p_1(x)/p_0(x)=x$ a.e."

Here  $p_1(x)/p_0(x)=dP_1/dP_0$

As long as I understood he means

$$\tilde{P}_0\left[\frac{d \tilde{P}_1}{d \tilde{P}_0}(X)\leq x\right]=P_0[X\leq x]$$

$$\tilde{P}_1\left[\frac{d \tilde{P}_1}{d \tilde{P}_0}(X)\leq x\right]=P_1[X\leq x]$$

then $$p_1(x)/p_0(x)=\frac{d \tilde{P}_1}{d \tilde{P}_0}(x)\quad \mbox{a.e}$$

This is my try: [image]

> Is it true?

he was trying to say that

$$P_0[Y<y]\geq \tilde{P}_0[Y<y]$$ and $$P_1[Y<y]\leq \tilde{P}_1[Y<y]$$ could be extended to $$P_0[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]\geq \tilde{P}_0[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]$$ and $$P_1[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]\leq \tilde{P}_1[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]$$
with his statement above.

> How is it possible at all?

Comment: Here, the author (As is standard in probability theory) is saying the word "distribution" for the pushforward of $P_0$ or $P_1$ via the radon nikodym derivative of $P_1$ wrt $P_0$.  I think you can fill in the details of proving that the claim is actually true by using the radon Nikodym chain rule.

Comment: @Jeff I think I also used some sort of chain rule in my trial. I wonder also what is the implication of this thing. Because he is claiming that $P_0[Y<y]\geq \tilde{P}_0[Y<y]$ and $P_1[Y<y]\leq \tilde{P}_1[Y<y]$ could be extended to $P_0[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]\geq \tilde{P}_0[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]$ and $P_1[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]\leq \tilde{P}_1[\tilde{p}_1(Y)/\tilde{p}_0(Y)<t]$.

Comment: I think that the title is missing a "the" somewhere before "Author" (which probably shouldn't be written with a capital letter, while we're at it, unless the author's name is in fact Author).

Comment: @AsafKaragila how about if he is big guy?))